# Symfony2 how to add 2 Entities to 1 Form Type

Tags: php, forms, symfony, checkbox, entity

I have 2 entities, Tour and Destination, like this

Tour:

```
<?php

namespace HearWeGo\HearWeGoBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * Tour
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="HearWeGo\HearWeGoBundle\Entity\Repository\TourRepository")
 */
class Tour
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="This field must be filled")
     * 
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="startdate", type="datetime")
     * @Assert\DateTime()
     */
    private $startdate;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="enddate", type="datetime")
     * @Assert\DateTime()
     */
    private $enddate;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="status", type="boolean")
     */
    private $status;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="discount", type="integer")
     */
    private $discount;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="info", type="text")
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="This field must be filled")
     * 
     */
    private $info;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="HearWeGo\HearWeGoBundle\Entity\Company", inversedBy="tours")
     */
    private $company;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="HearWeGo\HearWeGoBundle\Entity\Destination", mappedBy="tours")
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="This field must be filled")
     * 
     */
    private $destinations;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->destinations = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return Tour
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set startdate
     *
     * @param \DateTime $startdate
     * @return Tour
     */
    public function setStartdate($startdate)
    {
        $this->startdate = $startdate;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get startdate
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getStartdate()
    {
        return $this->startdate;
    }

    /**
     * Set enddate
     *
     * @param \DateTime $enddate
     * @return Tour
     */
    public function setEnddate($enddate)
    {
        $this->enddate = $enddate;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get enddate
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getEnddate()
    {
        return $this->enddate;
    }

    /**
     * Set status
     *
     * @param string $status
     * @return Tour
     */
    public function setStatus($status)
    {
        $this->status = $status;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get status
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getStatus()
    {
        return $this->status;
    }

    /**
     * Set discount
     *
     * @param integer $discount
     * @return Tour
     */
    public function setDiscount($discount)
    {
        $this->discount = $discount;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get discount
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getDiscount()
    {
        return $this->discount;
    }

    /**
     * Set info
     *
     * @param string $info
     * @return Tour
     */
    public function setInfo($info)
    {
        $this->info = $info;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get info
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getInfo()
    {
        return $this->info;
    }

    /**
     * Set company
     *
     * @param \HearWeGo\HearWeGoBundle\Entity\Company $company
     * @return Tour
     */
    public function setCompany(\HearWeGo\HearWeGoBundle\Entity\Company $company = null)
    {
        $this->company = $company;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get company
     *
     * @return \HearWeGo\HearWeGoBundle\Entity\Company 
     */
    public function getCompany()
    {
        return $this->company;
    }

    /**
     * Add destinations
     *
     * @param \HearWeGo\HearWeGoBundle\Entity\Destination $destinations
     * @return Tour
     */
    public function addDestination(\HearWeGo\HearWeGoBundle\Entity\Destination $destinations)
    {
        $this->destinations[] = $destinations;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove destinations
     *
     * @param \HearWeGo\HearWeGoBundle\Entity\Destination $destinations
     */
    public function removeDestination(\HearWeGo\HearWeGoBundle\Entity\Destination $destinations)
    {
        $this->destinations->removeElement($destinations);
    }

    /**
     * Get destinations
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getDestinations()
    {
        return $this->destinations;
    }

}
```

Destination:

```
<?php

namespace HearWeGo\HearWeGoBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * Destination
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="HearWeGo\HearWeGoBundle\Entity\Repository\DestinationRepository")
 */
class Destination
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="This field must be filled")
     * 
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="location", type="decimal")
     */
    private $location;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="HearWeGo\HearWeGoBundle\Entity\Audio", mappedBy="destination")
     */
    private $audio;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="HearWeGo\HearWeGoBundle\Entity\Article", mappedBy="destination")
     */
    private $articles;


    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="HearWeGo\HearWeGoBundle\Entity\Tour", inversedBy="destinations")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="tours_destinations")
     */
    private $tours;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->article = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->tours = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return Destination
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set location
     *
     * @param string $location
     * @return Destination
     */
    public function setLocation($location)
    {
        $this->location = $location;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get location
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getLocation()
    {
        return $this->location;
    }

    /**
     * Add audio
     *
     * @param \HearWeGo\HearWeGoBundle\Entity\Audio $audio
     * @return Destination
     */
    public function addAudio(\HearWeGo\HearWeGoBundle\Entity\Audio $audio)
    {
        $this->audio[] = $audio;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove audio
     *
     * @param \HearWeGo\HearWeGoBundle\Entity\Audio $audio
     */
    public function removeAudio(\HearWeGo\HearWeGoBundle\Entity\Audio $audio)
    {
        $this->audio->removeElement($audio);
    }

    /**
     * Get audio
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getAudio()
    {
        return $this->audio;
    }

    /**
     * Add articles
     *
     * @param \HearWeGo\HearWeGoBundle\Entity\Article $articles
     * @return Destination
     */
    public function addArticle(\HearWeGo\HearWeGoBundle\Entity\Article $articles)
    {
        $this->articles[] = $articles;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove articles
     *
     * @param \HearWeGo\HearWeGoBundle\Entity\Article $articles
     */
    public function removeArticle(\HearWeGo\HearWeGoBundle\Entity\Article $articles)
    {
        $this->articles->removeElement($articles);
    }

    /**
     * Get articles
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getArticles()
    {
        return $this->articles;
    }

    /**
     * Add tours
     *
     * @param \HearWeGo\HearWeGoBundle\Entity\Tour $tours
     * @return Destination
     */
    public function addTour(\HearWeGo\HearWeGoBundle\Entity\Tour $tours)
    {
        $this->tours[] = $tours;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove tours
     *
     * @param \HearWeGo\HearWeGoBundle\Entity\Tour $tours
     */
    public function removeTour(\HearWeGo\HearWeGoBundle\Entity\Tour $tours)
    {
        $this->tours->removeElement($tours);
    }

    /**
     * Get tours
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getTours()
    {
        return $this->tours;
    }
}
```

The Form Type I build like this

```
<?php

namespace HearWeGo\HearWeGoBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class CompanySubmitTourType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name','text')
            ->add('startdate','datetime')
            ->add('enddate','datetime')
            ->add('discount','number')
            ->add('info','text')
            ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array('data_class'=>"HearWeGo\HearWeGoBundle\Entity\Tour"));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'company_submit_tour';
    }
}
```

In Controller that handles it

```
/**
     * @Route("/company/submit",name="company_submit")
     */
    public function submitTourAction(Request $request)
    {
        $tour=new Tour();
        $form=$this->createForm(new CompanySubmitTourType(),$tour,array('method'=>'POST','action'=>$this->generateUrl('company_submit')));
        $repository=$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('HearWeGoHearWeGoBundle:Destination')->findAll();
        $dest_arr=array();
        $form_check=$this->createFormBuilder($dest_arr,array('method'=>'POST','action'=>$this->generateUrl('company_submit')));
        $i=0;
        foreach ($repository as $item)
        {
            $i++;
            $form_check->add('destination','checkbox',array('label'=>$item->getName()));
        }
        $form_check->add('submit','submit');
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($request->getMethod()=='POST')
        {
            if ($form->isValid())
            {
                $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

                $em->persist($tour);
                $em->flush();
                return new Response("<html>".$tour->getName()." has been created!</html>");
            }
        }
        return $this->render('HearWeGoHearWeGoBundle:Company:companySubmit.html.twig',array('form1'=>$form->createView(),'form2'=>$form_check->getForm()->createView()));
    }
```

As you can see, I have to use 2 forms:
`$form` is used to to persist data to Tour entity
`$form_check` is used to get list of all records in Destination table in my database, then display checkboxes for user to choose more than one option of destination
I want that when user clicks on Submit button, a new record is created in Tour table in my database, and a list of checked Destination objects is also in data persisted
But 2 forms cannot send POST method at once
I've failed to add name of all records in CompanySubmitTourType in vain, so I don't know what to do now, even when I add this line into Form Type

`->add('destinations','entity',array('class'=>'HearWeGoHearWeGoBundle:Destination','property'=>'name'))`

Then replace `$form_check->add` with `$form->add` in loop in Controller, it only shows me a dropdown menu in which I can only choose one, not multiple choice like I want to do. So please help me solve. I want to use checkbox to allow user to select multiple choices

Comment: you need to embed the other form. have a read of [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html)